# How to design storyboard for specific devices instead of size classes

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, uistoryboard, size-classes

I have been using **size classes** till **Xcode 7** for all my UI needs and started using **Vary for Traits** from **Xcode 8** but when I want to make **device specific changes**

Mostly iPhone 4s,iPhone 5s and iPhone 6 falls in the same size class i.e **Compact width Regular height** and this is where I am facing the problem

I couldn't do it in storyboard easily I always have to write code swift or objective c to make it happen.

Is there any standard way to achieve through storyboard or interface builder ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of my questions similar to you.

[What is the proper way to calculate Left, right, top, bottom constraint according to different devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43665777/how-to-design-storyboard-for-specific-devices-instead-of-size-classes)

By the way i follow your approach too but after **stackView** it is so much easier than before.I don't have to pull all the nslayoutconstraint and do multiply with aspect ratio very much.

So my suggestion is to use **stackView**

Reason: At least you don't have to write so much code(multiply by aspect ratio,i guess)

Comment: its supported from iOS 9 only

Comment: if you want something better u may sacrifice something for that. :)